# regex match two sets of digits from line

Tags: java, regex

Matching two sets of numbers from a line. (2.66 and 34.3).
These can digits are variable in length but surrounded by whitespace. eg
`Ox   2.66 abcda   34.3 abfdasd`

I got 2.66 with `\b(?:Ox)\s+(\d*\.*?\d+)`

Any resources that can guide me in the right direction? Im stuck on matching the second separately.
cheers

Comment: This pattern works for me on regex101.com: `\s+(\d*\.*?\d+)\s+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may continue the regex pattern and capture the second number after another word:

```
\bOx\s+(\d*\.?\d+)\s+\S+\s+(\d*\.?\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gn3nJh/1). The second number will be in Group 2.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Ox` - a word `Ox`
- `\s+` -  one or more whitespaces
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: zero or more digits, an optional `.`, one or more digits
- `\s+` -  one or more whitespaces
- `\S+` -  one or more non-whitespaces
- `\s+` -  one or more whitespaces
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 2: zero or more digits, an optional `.`, one or more digits.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Nxy23a):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "Ox   2.66 abcda   34.3 abfdasd";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bOx\\s+(\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\d*\\.?\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // => 2.66
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // => 34.3
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the following regular expression: `([\d\D\s]*)`.
If you want numeric values only then `([\d\.]*)`.